# One of two same (size and configuration) Android devices not recognized when debug mode activated

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have two android tablets that are exactly the same i.e. hardware, same android version: 5.1 and each has activated debug mode.

The first one is recognized by adb and I can work and push my app but the second one is only recognized as a usb device by windows when debug mode is deactivated. So I cannot use the second tablet on android studio and I can't find any hint on the problem source.

FYI:

- No-brand devices
- CPU : MTK6582
- Android version : 5.1
- Android studio

Thank you verry much for your help.

---

Edit : 
I used the USBDview software to get some info, here is a screenshot showing the results of the two devices.
VendorID value is 0000 in debug mode but is 0e8d when it is deactivated which is the same value as the first device's (cf. bottom).

[click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XKtn.png)

Comment: what brands and models of your tablets? The problem might be in drivers, that you have for first and haven't for second

Comment: can you read both of them in device manager under android phone??

Comment: There is no brand on the tablets, they are just samples, so no brand or model, at least none that are public.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ Mina Fawzy: no, only the first one is visible and working.
the "adb devices" command shows nothing for the second tablet.

Comment: see if those commands produce different output for your 2 devices http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: Check the usb connector of the second device - see if the data pin is not missing, bent or has some dirt on it.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you install driver of each device correctly

if this dosent work restart adb

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

hope this help

Comment: Tried that but it did not help. 
The devices are from the same manufacturer and the drivers are supposed to be the same.
Thank you anyway.